# Google Geocoding API Limit

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-api, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoder

Google maps and geocoding functions have a request limit.

With Google Maps the limit is 25000 maps load per day, and is a limit that depends by your apikey

So if there are 25000 users and each user has made a request, you have exceeded the limit, and in your Google API Console you can see your quota for :

-Ad Exchange Buyer API

-AdSense Management API

-Analytics API

-Audit API

-Calendar API

-Google+ API

-Latitude API

-Static Maps API

-Street View Image API

-Translate API

-Identity Toolkit API

With Geocoding the limit is only 2500 request per day, and in my Google API Console there isn't showed a quota, 
Mean that the limit is related to the user IP and not to the developer certificate or I missing something!??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2500 a day is by IP address. That means your server makes webservices requests, it counts against the 2500. When a client opens a browser, and loads your map and does a geocoding request, it counts against the 2500 for that client.

The 25K a day is counted based on map loads, not requests. A map load is defined as loading the JS loader. Here's the definition of a map load:
https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_mapload

Comment: 2500 a day per ip address?! that means the same api key can generate an amount of calls 2500 times the number of clients. That's a huge number for a single api key, or application. Are you sure about it? I am not aware this is documented by Google anywhere.

Comment: The Geocoding API doesn't use a key

Comment: Am using invocation of this form - is ther any issue with this approach: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?